# Why doesn't changing a variable in a script alter it outside the script?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

Let's say I `export` a variable with the terminal. After that I call a script that alters that variable to something else. But when I return to the terminal and `echo` the variable, it remains as its original value.

What can I do if I want like the variable to be changed and visible outside the script, not only there *in* the script. Here's an example of what I want to say:

```
ares@ares-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ export package=tree
ares@ares-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ cat script3.sh 

#! /bin/bash
#set -x
echo $package
apt-cache show $1 | head -1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    package=1
else
    package=0
fi
echo $package
```

Output when running script

```
ares@ares-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ ./script3.sh gnome-terminal
tree
Package: gnome-terminal
1
ares@ares-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ echo $package
tree
ares@ares-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$
```

Answer (score 6):

Your shell process has a copy of the parent's environment and no access the parent process's environment whatsoever. When your shell process terminates any changes you've made to its environment are lost. Sourcing a script file is the most commonly used method for configuring a shell environment, you may just want to bite the bullet and maintain one for each of the two flavors of shell.

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496777)

Answer (score 2):

source yourfile.sh

This should do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create a function in your .bashrc, and call that function within the current shell; this will save a little typing. You can still pass variables.

This is the method I use instead of an alias if I need a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

New process get **copy** of each exported variable.

You need to do one of:

- do all operation on the same process (by sourcing the script in current shell)
- keep value in common place (sqlite, flat file) and read/write it from each process